# How to synchronously call DiscoveryClient.Find in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, service-discovery

I'm trying to discover a service using DiscoveryClient from an ASP.NET page

```
void Page_Load(...) {
    ...
    var result = DiscoveryClient.Find(anyCriteria);
    ....
}
```

The call fails whith an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Asynchronous operations are not allowed in this context

StackTrace:

> at System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext.OperationStarted()
>     at System.ServiceModel.Discovery.DiscoveryClient.InitializeAsyncOperation(AsyncOperationContext context)
>     at System.ServiceModel.Discovery.DiscoveryClient.FindAsyncOperation(FindCriteria criteria, Object userState)
>     at System.ServiceModel.Discovery.DiscoveryClient.FindAsync(FindCriteria criteria, Object userState)
>     at System.ServiceModel.Discovery.DiscoveryClient.Find(FindCriteria criteria)

I tried using `<%Page ... Async="true" %>` without any change.

How do I call DiscoveryClient.Find in an ASP.NET page correctly?

Comment: This should be a common use case of ws-discovery, right?

Answer (score 2):

Did you set (web.config)

```
<appSettings>
     <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975440.aspx

"Setting this compatibility switch is mandatory for WebSockets-enabled applications, for using Task-based asynchrony in Web Forms pages, and for certain other asynchronous behaviors."

I'm pretty sure that the latest discovery client uses the TPL.

Comment: AFAIK this is the default for .NET 4.5. I tried with 4.0 and 4.5. The synchronization context class in the stack trace are different, but it doesn't work in both. Anyway, I give it a try, tomorrow.

Comment: @MichaelStoll Hmm, the doc is fairly specific. "If this key value is set to false [default], asynchronous code paths in ASP.NET 4.5 behave as they did in ASP.NET 4.0"

Comment: Tried it, unfortunately without success. I took a look with ILSpy. The default for .NET 4.5 is true, the default for .NET 4.0 false. The exception is slightly different. (Replace AspNetSynchronizationContext in stack trace with LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext)

Answer (score 1):

The AllowAsyncDuringSyncStages option has to be set to 'true'.

```
<appSettings>
      <add key="aspnet:AllowAsyncDuringSyncStages" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

This only works with AspNetSynchronizationContext, which is enforced by the UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext setting. See Kenneth's answer for details.

Comment: I'm still open to better answers. I don't like the idea of having to change the behavior of the whole app for this.

Comment: This solved it for me. Did you ever find a better solution?

Comment: No, nothing new to report here.